# Azure Authentication and Dynamics CRM

Tags: azure, postman, microsoft-dynamics

When a user fills out a contact form on my site, I want to put that data into Dynamics CRM as a new lead. I keep getting a 401 error when I use my access_token to hit the CRM.

Following step from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service

---

## Step 1.

Get Access Token with Client Credentials (I'm just using Postman).

**POST**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my_tenat_id}/oauth2/token
```

**BODY**

```
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:{my_client_id}
resource:https://{my_organization}.crm.dynamics.com   
client_secret:{client_secret}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "3600",
  "ext_expires_in": "0",
  "expires_on": "1491514124",
  "not_before": "1491510224",
  "resource": "https://{my_organization}.crm.dynamics.com",
  "access_token": "abc{...}"
 }
```

## Step 2.

Access Dynamics CRM API. I am just requesting basic list of contacts for now.

**GET**

```
https://{my_organization}.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1/contacts?$select=fullname
```

**Headers**

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Accept:application/json
OData-Version:4.0
Authorization:Bearer abc{...}
```

**Response**

```
HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied
```

---

**What am I missing?** I feel like something must be misconfigured but I don't know where to look.

Comment: Do you have any further information on the error? [This blog post](http://phuocle.net/crm/dynamics-365-online-s2s-authentication-full-explain.aspx) resolves a 401 error by introducing an Application User.

Comment: @Dave Clark Thanks! - I had this same issue and that blog was the answer - In the article he's using the SDK client, but the solution is the same (I'm using postman too).